# What would cause a Hex and RGB value to differ between online and photoshop?

Tags: css, rgb, hex

```
style {
background-color: rgb(224,224,195);
}
```

Should be the same as:

```
style {
background-color: #f4e0c3;
}
```

According to Photoshop which I checked a few times:

[image]

But when I use the RGB value in my CSS I'm getting this:

[image]

If I use the Hex value, I get the color that I was expecting:

[image]

Any idea what the difference is so I can be aware of it in the future? I've never had, or at least never noticed, any problems with RGB() before.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a typo and not helpful to future readers

Comment: @ZachSaucier so questions about code that is not working isn't allowed??

Comment: For questions dealing with typographic errors, I think they shouldn't be allowed. As stated, I don't think this will be helpful to anyone who comes across it in the future. There's even a close reason on StackOverflow for this specific reason

Comment: It has nothing to do with it being code or not (other than the fact that it is typed and prone to typos) @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** There IS a typo in your code :))

You wrote `rgb(224,224,195);` instead of `rgb(244,224,195);`

---

Are you sure there isn't any kind of typo in your code? Cause I could not replicate your issue:

[image]

Here, try my code and see if this comes up the same way:

```
.hex,
.rgb{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#f4e0c3;
}
.rgb{
    background:rgb(244, 224, 195);
}

<div class="hex">
</div>
<div class="rgb">
</div>
```

Anyway, whatever it is, since I could not replicate it, it must be local. Maybe browser related?

Comment: Hah not only was there a typo but I made the same typo writing the question --- 224, 224 shouldve been 244, 224 . Thanks, im gonna go have another coffee now

Comment: Cheers @Ryan, enjoy the coffee ! :D